# Face of roof somehow deleted and I can't put it back

Tags: modeling, vertices, faces, edges, geometry

I somehow deleted a face to my roof... I tried the fill (f) key but it doesn't fill it in all the way... The second picture is what it does when I fill it in... How can I fill it in like it was before?

Edit: here is the link to the blend file [image]

[image: Deleted face]
[image: Filled in face]
[image: Attempt at fixing]
[image: Attempt at fixing 2]

Comment: Please share your Blend file via https://blend-exchange.com/ so that we can have a look. Follow the instructions on that page.

Comment: @JohnEason I updated my post with the Blender file...

Comment: Sorry. - Different time zones? You have overlapping edges and vertices on the surround to that hole. Select All in Edit mode and then hit M > Merge by Distance. That will get rid of most of the issues. Then go to Edge mode and Shift-select the surrounding edges of the hole and F > Fill. There will still be some overlapping edges there but at least the hole will be filled!

Comment: No I was just busy and it was late when I commented... Morning time for me... Anyways I select all the vertices? You said all but I'd think it would cause issues if I merged all vertices of the roof... And how can I fix the overlapping edges?

Comment: Hit 'A' in Edit mode to select everything and 'M' > Merge > By distance and you'll see in the bottom status bar that 31 vertices have been merged. This will not cause any issues with the roof. I'm not sure how you actually built the model so it's a bit difficult to say how you should get rid of the excess edges, but you can dissolve most of the verts along the sides of the triangle without causing any problem as they aren't actually doing anything. That will get rid of most of the overlapping edges. Can't help much further as this site isn't really for detailed instructions.

Comment: @JohnEason as you can see, I just edited the post with more photos... When I do what you say and highlight the surrounding areas, and then fill it creates a small triangle on the right side that is different than the rest... How can I fix this? It did this before when I tried to fill... If possible could you post on an actual answer so you can type more?

Answer (score 0):

This is using your Blend file.
Firstly <kbd>A</kbd> to select All in Edit mode and <kbd>M</kbd> > <kbd>Merge by Distance</kbd> which shows that 31 verts are merged as shown below
[image]

Although it's not strictly necessary, I then <kbd>Shift</kbd>-selected the ringed verts below and dissolved them using <kbd>X</kbd> > <kbd>Dissolve Vertices</kbd> which got rid of duplicate edges

[image]

Then go into <kbd>Edge</kbd> mode and  <kbd>Shift</kbd>-select the edges surrounding the hole

[image]

<kbd>F</kbd> to fill the hole with a new face

[image]

Comment: Would give you an upvote if I had more reputation... I was successful though... I appreciate your help though my friend :)